# What is the meaning of "Giraffe can see things from a great distance"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Giraffe can see things from a great distance" ?

Does it mean "Things is far from the giraffe. Giraffe can see things that is far from giraffe" or "Giraffe is far from things. Giraffe that is far from things can see things"?

Comment: Where did your examples come from? They either aren't grammatical or don't make sense.

Comment: Source: Giraffe by Jose Luls Garcia Sanchez and Miguel Angel Pacheco.

Comment: Written in English? Or are the examples a translation from original Spanish?

Comment: According to [this source](http://www.worldcat.org/title/giraffe/oclc/10585712) it is a juvenile book translated from Spanish. Grammatically it should be either "Giraffes" or "A giraffe". If the quote is correct (singular with no article) then it's unfortunate. The question seems clear regardless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on an ungrammatical English translation of a Spanish book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means

> Giraffe can see things that are far from the giraffe.

Comment: Correct, but nevertheless a very low-quality answer that should not have been selected.  Why repeat an ungrammatical sentence?  Surely it would take only minimal effort to fix it by adding a simple "the".

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the two proposed sentences is very similar.

*<sub>(I'm using  corrected language below)</sub>*

**Things are far from the giraffe** and **the giraffe is far from things** have exactly the same meaning.

**A Giraffe can see things that are far from it** and **A giraffe that is far from things can see them** have almost the same meaning; the second one can imply that a giraffe can see anything that is far from it (even if it's hidden) while the first doesn't suggest that.

Based on that, the first sentence is probably closer to the original meaning.